# What's wrong with my sql statement in R? Can not find the min of field

Tags: sql, r

I have field `ID`(int)  and `OperationDate`(datetime) in my database `[DB].[dbo].[OperationRecord]`.

I supposed to find the min of the `ID` that the `OperationDate` start with 2019.

The query works in SQL SERVER but I got error in RStudio:

```
result <- db_read(con,"SELECT MIN([ID]) FROM [DB].[dbo].[OperationRecord]
      WHERE DATEPART(yy, [OperationDate]) = 2019")
```

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]'zzz1' ・ [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.  'SELECT * FROM
>   (SELECT MIN([ID]) FROM [DB].[dbo].[OperationRecord]
>         WHERE DATEPART(yy, [OperationDate]) = 2019) "zzz6" WHERE (0 = 1)'

By the way the following query works:

```
result <- db_read(con,"SELECT [ID] FROM [DB].[dbo].[OperationRecord]
      WHERE DATEPART(yy, [OperationDate]) = 2019")
```

And the function `db_read()` is from [healthcareai](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/healthcareai/versions/2.3.0/topics/db_read)

What am I supposed to do with the `min()` here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) I'm curious/concerned about the `where (0=1)` added to your query. Do you know what that's from? (2) Similarly, `zzz1` and `zzz6`. Are those from anything you're doing? (3) Why kind of field is `[ID]`; if it is an id field for the row, it seems odd to treat it like a number when id fields are often (typically?) categorical (not ordinal) in nature ... but I admit I'm projecting here.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I think I found the reason. I declare the field name in query statement like SELECT MIN([ID]) AS MIN_ID FROM [DB].[dbo].[OperationRecord]...and then it worked.